# Cheap flights in South-East Asia

Tags: air-travel, budget, southeast-asia

What companies offering domestic flights in Thailand and countries near it like Cambodia, Laos, Vietnam, Burma?

Currently needed directions are:

```
Bangkok-Angkor
Chiang Mai- Angkor
Angkor-Hanoi
Hanoi-Saigon 
Bangkok-Bagan
```

Comment: your question is too broad. You're looking for flights to Thailand, but where from?

Comment: I have updated list of destinations currently needed.

Comment: but where from? Or are you restricting it to flights only in those five countries?

Comment: Yes, I need flights in these countries

Comment: surely you can search this online? there are a TON of flight search sites.

Answer (score 5):

Wikipedia is your friend, their airport articles are generally very up to date about who flies where.  For example, the [Siem Reap Airport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siem_Reap_Airport) article will (correctly) tell you the following connections from Siem Reap/Angkor:

- Bangkok: only options are Bangkok Airways and Cambodia Angkor, neither of them cheap
- Chiang Rai: no flights at all
- Hanoi: Cambodia Angkor, Vietnam or Sky Wings

Or try the friendly maps at [OpenFlights](http://openflights.org):

- [Siem Reap](http://openflights.org/airport/REP)
- [Hanoi](http://openflights.org/airport/HAN)
- [Nyaung U (Bagan)](http://openflights.org/airport/HAN)

In short, the only one of those sectors that's flown by a real LCC is Saigon-Hanoi, which is served by [Jetstar Pacific](http://www.jetstar.com/vn/en/home).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that this is an SE-format question, or will really be answerable, but to add to the list:

Nok Air,
Orient Thai Airlines (1-2-Go until they had a couple 1-2-crashes)
.. are Thai Budget airlines, mostly domestic flights

Thai Airlines,
Bangkok Air
.. are 'normal', also mostly domestic

Air Asia has many routes in the area.   Lao Airlines does what you'd imagine (regional flights b/w Lao and, mostly, capitals).

There are few worthwhile flights from CNX to anywhere else (you mostly either need to, or would be better off transferring through BKK/DMK).